# Using azure service bus, how do I publish a single message to multiple queues?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a single client application that will publish the message to a single location/target, and I need that message to then end up in 3 separate other queues as well ( and subsequently processed) 
Basically here is the use case:
A website collects customers information in a lead form. That lead information is pushed to an restful web api. The restfull web api then publishes a message to a single location and then returns a success result to client. In the background, the message ends up on 4 queues, and ultimately sent to 4 different other web services (some external, some internal)

The system needs to be performant with respect to how quickly all 4 of the queues are processed from the 4 queues. But the volume of leads is not necessarily extremely high. (perhaps a few hundred leads per day)

Here is an image of what I am thinking
[image: message flow]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Topic in combination with the autoforwarding feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding

A single publish to a topic could then be setup to auto-forward to 4 separate queues.

Comment: so I’m your proposal above , the number of subscriptions is 0?

Comment: In regards to your diagram yes.

The web API would send a message to the Topic.
Topic would auto forward the message to the 4 different queues.
Various web servers would each be connected and receiving from their respective queues.

Comment: How exactly do I configure a topic to forward to more than 1 queue?

Comment: My apologies, you will need the 4 subscriptions to use the forward feature. 
Add 4 subscriptions to the topic and each can forward to a different queue cutting out a step in your diagram. Service Bus Explorer is a nice tool to help set up and visualise.
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases

Comment: thank you. This appears to be a viable solution for me as I have tested this setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of uses Queues, you should use [Topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview#topics):

> a queue is often used for point-to-point communication, topics are useful in publish/subscribe scenarios.

Topics and subscriptions provide a "one-to-many" form of communication, using a publish/subscribe pattern.

If you really need to use a Queue there is no other way than to send copies of the message to the different queues.

Comment: how do you feel about the concept shown on my diagram above? Can I use azure functions triggered off the subscription to publish to each individual queue?

Answer (score 1):

One best solution to solve your business scenario, is using a Service Bus Topic with four Topic Subscriptions. You can send the message to the topic. You can create filters (or) [Topic subscription rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) to filter the messages received by the Service Bus Topic.

You can then set the [auto-forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) property of each topic subscription to the desired Service Bus Queue.